# Why is there a stitched hole in the back pocket of my new jersey?

Tags: clothes

I just finished a charity ride and found that the brand new jersey bought for it has a hole in the back center pocket.  It is neatly cut, with stitching around it to prevent fraying, so I'm sure it is a feature rather than a defect.  What is the intended purpose?

Comment: found your spelling a little hard to understand, please feel free to revert my changes if they didn't help.

Comment: Thanks for correcting it, it was written on my phone at the finish line :-D

Comment: I've seen small holes in some relatively waterproof garments that I assumed were to let water run out.

Comment: You also see similar holes in, eg, the fronts of police uniform shirts, intended to allow badges to be applied without damaging the fabric.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My best guess is the hole would allow a headphone cable to run down the collar, through the inside of the shirt, and into the pocket.

Comment: It seems this is correct, the manufacturer's site (www.pactimo.com) mentions an "MP3/race radio opening in rear pocket" as a feature for some of their cycling jerseys.

Comment: That's terrible that they advertise it as MP3/race radio (I don't think headphones on bikes are a good idea). They could have just labelled it 'for race radio headphones' to not upset fogies like myself...

Comment: Just a thought. It could also be good to use to run a power cord from an external battery pack to a head lamp for night time mountain bike riding.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess the garmet manufacturer puts the hole there so that when you wash the jersey (which hopefully you do occasionaly), water doesn't pool in the pocket but instead drains out the hole.

This doesn't really explain why it's only in the center pocket and not the side ones ...

Comment: That would be a good feature on a watertight jersey, but in this case the jersey is just a regular jersey with lots of moisture-wicking ability

Comment: Draining Slowly => Lots of stress on seams, Draining Fast => Less stress on seams...

Answer (score 2):

I remember that decades ago when wool cycling jerseys were common, the middle pocket in the back sometimes had a button and button hole. You could button the largest pocket. I don't remember if the other pockets also had buttons and button holes. My guess is that the stitched hole is a vestigial button hole from an old jersey style.

Answer (score -1):

For some sort of cord to make life easier.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. It is unclear what you are trying to convey with such a short answer. Please see our help center for information about [how to write a good answer](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). A short, one line post like this is likely to be downvoted, flagged, and ultimately deleted.